# jawr - Included file in jsp contains numeric folder that does not exist

Tags: javascript, jawr

I am using jawr to combine and minify javascript. But in jspo when i include `<jawr:script src="content/js/bundles/home.js">`

It generates.....

http://localhost:8080/APP_JIG_HEAD/**999485638**/content/js/bundles/home.js

goes to 404.

That numeric folder does not exist anywhere in tomcat.

While searching found only 2 home.js

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\work\Catalina\localhost\APP_JIG_HEAD\jawrTmp\gzip\content\js\bundles\home.js

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\work\Catalina\localhost\APP_JIG_HEAD\jawrTmp\text\content\js\bundles\home.js

my jawr.prop is as below.

```
# Common properties
jawr.debug.on=false
jawr.gzip.on=false
jawr.gzip.ie6.on=false
jawr.charset.name=UTF-8

# Javascript properties and mappings
jawr.js.bundle.basedir=/js

# The remaining scripts will be served sepparately.
jawr.js.bundle.home.id=/content/js/bundles/home.js
jawr.js.bundle.home.mappings=/content/js/MyHomeNew.js, /content/js/MyHome.js
```

Comment: Are you in development mode? Is this a result of the [`useRandomParam`](http://jawr.java.net/docs/taglibs.html) default value?

Comment: No. I was in development mode....Its normal mode now...In development mode it generates individual files. And random number is at end. Here, Its folder name like this.

Comment: Hope you solved your problem since but... I had the same problem in the past week and to solve it I had to re-edit my mappings to jawr servlet / jawr controller (if you use Spring).

Comment: Map you servlet dispatcher with *.css, *.js
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68494386/6785456