# Jawr & Springboot - Resources folders not resolved

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jawr

my problem is that the bundle of css & js files are not resolved.

I am migrating my WAR application to a Spring Boot application.

Here is the servlet 3.0 configuration for jawr :

```
@Configuration
public class WebJawrConfiguration {

    private final Properties properties;

    public WebJawrConfiguration(final WebSelfiscProperties webProperties) {
        this.properties = new Properties();
        this.properties.putAll(webProperties.getJawr().entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> "jawr." + e.getKey(), Entry::getValue)));
    }

    @Bean
    public JawrSpringController jawrBinaryController() {
        final JawrSpringController jawrBinaryController = new JawrSpringController();
        jawrBinaryController.setConfiguration(properties);
        jawrBinaryController.setType(JawrConstant.BINARY_TYPE);
        return jawrBinaryController;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("jawrBinaryController")
    public JawrSpringController jawrCssController() {
        final JawrSpringController jawrCssController = new JawrSpringController();
        jawrCssController.setConfiguration(properties);
        jawrCssController.setType(JawrConstant.CSS_TYPE);
        // jawrCssController.setMapping("/public/bundles/css");
        return jawrCssController;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("jawrCssController")
    public JawrSpringController jawrJsController() {
        final JawrSpringController jawrJsController = new JawrSpringController();
        jawrJsController.setConfiguration(properties);
        jawrJsController.setType(JawrConstant.JS_TYPE);
        // jawrJsController.setMapping("/public/bundles/js");
        return jawrJsController;
    }

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "jawrHandlerMapping")
    @DependsOn("jawrJsController")
    public class jawrHandlerMappingConfiguration {

        private final JawrSpringController jawrJsController;
        private final JawrSpringController jawrCssController;
        private final JawrSpringController jawrBinaryController;

        /**
         * Constructeur
         *
         * @param jawrJsController
         * @param jawrCssController
         * @param jawrBinaryController
         */
        public jawrHandlerMappingConfiguration(final JawrSpringController jawrJsController, final JawrSpringController jawrCssController, final JawrSpringController jawrBinaryController) {
            super();
            this.jawrJsController = jawrJsController;
            this.jawrCssController = jawrCssController;
            this.jawrBinaryController = jawrBinaryController;
        }

        @Bean
        public HandlerMapping jawrHandlerMapping() {
            final SimpleUrlHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
            handlerMapping.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

            final Map<String, Object> urlMap = new HashMap<>();
            urlMap.put("**/*.css", jawrCssController);
            urlMap.put("**/*.eot", jawrBinaryController);
            urlMap.put("**/*.gif", jawrBinaryController);
            urlMap.put("**/*.ico", jawrBinaryController);
            urlMap.put("**/*.jpg", jawrBinaryController);
            urlMap.put("**/*.jpeg", jawrBinaryController);
            urlMap.put("**/*.js", jawrJsController);
            urlMap.put("**/*.png", jawrBinaryController);
            urlMap.put("**/*.ttf", jawrBinaryController);
            urlMap.put("**/*.woff", jawrBinaryController);
            urlMap.put("**/*.woff2", jawrBinaryController);
            urlMap.put("**/*.svg", jawrBinaryController);
            handlerMapping.setUrlMap(urlMap);

            return handlerMapping;
        }
    }
}
```

A part of may application.properties :

```
# Common properties
jawr.debug.on=false
jawr.gzip.on=false
jawr.gzip.ie6.on=false
jawr.charset.name=UTF-8

jawr.css.bundle.base.id=/base.css
jawr.css.bundle.base.mappings=/public/css/blue-theme.css,/public/css/main.css
```

And how it's declared in my JSP

```
<jawr:style src="/base.css" />
```

If I set jawr.debug.on=true
Everything is working fine:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/sel/public/css/blue-theme.css?d=1136145833">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/sel/public/css/main.css?d=762931402">
```

If I set jawr.debug.on=false
A hash prefixes the link to version it. But the id is no longer resolved.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/2096063500/base.css">
```

I have been trying to correct this problem for over a week. Without success.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue.

Here is my new configuration :

```
@Configuration
public class WebJawrConfiguration {

    private final Properties properties;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param webProperties
     */
    public WebJawrConfiguration(final WebSelfiscProperties webProperties) {
        this.properties = new Properties();
        this.properties.putAll(webProperties.getJawr().entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> "jawr." + e.getKey(), Entry::getValue)));
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("jawrBinaryController")
    public JawrSpringController jawrCssController() {
        final JawrSpringController jawrCssController = new JawrSpringController();
        final Properties propertiesCss = new Properties();
        propertiesCss.putAll(properties.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> !e.getKey().toString().contains("jawr.js"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)));
        jawrCssController.setConfiguration(propertiesCss);
        jawrCssController.setType(JawrConstant.CSS_TYPE);
        return jawrCssController;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("jawrCssController")
    public JawrSpringController jawrJsController() {
        final JawrSpringController jawrJsController = new JawrSpringController();
        final Properties propertiesJs = new Properties();
        propertiesJs.putAll(properties.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> !e.getKey().toString().contains("jawr.css"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)));
        jawrJsController.setConfiguration(propertiesJs);
        jawrJsController.setType(JawrConstant.JS_TYPE);
        return jawrJsController;
    }

    @Configuration
    @DependsOn("jawrJsController")
    public class jawrHandlerMappingConfiguration {

        private final JawrSpringController jawrJsController;
        private final JawrSpringController jawrCssController;


        /**
         * Constructor
         *
         * @param jawrJsController
         * @param jawrCssController
         */
        public jawrHandlerMappingConfiguration(final JawrSpringController jawrJsController, final JawrSpringController jawrCssController) {
            super();
            this.jawrJsController = jawrJsController;
            this.jawrCssController = jawrCssController;
        }

        @Bean
        @DependsOn("jawrJsController")
        public HandlerMapping jawrHandlerMapping() {
            final SimpleUrlHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
            handlerMapping.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

            final Map<String, Object> urlMap = new HashMap<>();
            urlMap.put("**/*.css", jawrCssController);
            urlMap.put("**/*.js", jawrJsController);
            handlerMapping.setUrlMap(urlMap);

            return handlerMapping;
        }
    }
}
```

And map my servlet dispatcher with *.css, *.js